# Generic NxM matrix from array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, generics, matrix

The purpose is to create a NxM matrix from an array of strings, ex:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[] {"1 2 3","4 5 6"}
```

Then the output matrix would be

```
Integer[][] matrix = new Integer[][] { {1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

The transformer should be generic enough that it can produce a matrix of Double, Integer...

for 1 dimension I was able to do it. Here is the code:

```
    /**
     * Construct a matrix row from string line
     * Example:
     * in  = "1.7 5.14 9"
     * out = new Double[] { 1.7 ,5.14,9}
     *
     * @param in               string to lineToRow
     * @param compatibleParser specialize parser
     * @param <E>              type
     * @return matrix row
     */
    public static <E> E[] lineToRow(String in, Function<String, E> compatibleParser) {
        final String[] els = in.split(" +"); /* ignore multiple spaces */
        final E[] res = (E[]) new Object[els.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : els) {
            res[i] = compatibleParser.apply(s);
            i++;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

and the test for it is like following:

```
    @Test
    public void stringLineToMatrixRow() {

        String line0 = "1 2 3";
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}, MatrixUtils.lineToRow(line0, Integer::parseInt));
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Double[]{1.7, 2.99, 3.8}, MatrixUtils.lineToRow("1.7   2.99 3.8", Double::valueOf));
    }
```

For 2 dims my only success is by "hard coding" the type, see ex:

```
   /**
     * TODO find a way to use something like E[][]
     */
    public static Double[][] lineToRow(String[] ins) {
        int i = 0;
        Double[][] res = new Double[ins.length][3]; //3 just for test
        for (String ss : ins) {
            int j = 0;
            final String[] els = ss.split(" +");
            for (String s : els) {
                res[i][j] = Double.valueOf(s);
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

It works for 1 dim array because this line (from example 1) is ok:

> final E[] res = (E[]) new Object[els.length];
>   **but not for E[][] ...**

*NB: This is migrated from codereview.stackexchange as suggested by its communauty*

Comment: Have you considered using `List`s? You can create generic versions of them without casting.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon do you mean something like List<List<T>> ?

Comment: Yes. I'd use a `List<List<T>>`.

Comment: You can work in your method with lists, and convert them to arrays for returning them, if returning an array is a requirement